# Installing applications in a script in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

When I install an application via `sudo apt-get install application`, there is a prompt indicating the amount of disk space the application will fill and asks whether or not I want to continue. To continue I would type `y` and enter.

If I put the command in a script, how can I have the `y` and enter execute automatically?

Comment: `yes|sudo apt-get install ..` or `sudo apt-get -y install ...`; RTFM ;-)

Comment: @PSkocik. Hey I'll accept this if you care to post as an answer.

Comment: OK. Thx. I like points. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use `yes` to supply an infinite amount of `y`'s:

```
yes|sudo apt-get install ...
```

or you can use the `-y` flag for `apt-get install`

```
sudo apt-get -y install ...
```

Alternatively, you can use `--force-yes` with `apt-get` to force even potentially dangerous actions. (See `man apt-get` for more information about options to `apt-get`.)